# If different realities can’t have probabilities, does this mean no reality is more reasonable to believe than another?

Tags: metaphysics, probability, belief

This question is ultimately a follow up to [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/42942/is-it-valid-to-calculate-the-probability-of-different-metaphysical-realities?rq=1)

For the context of the question, assume that a metaphysical reality is a reality that can be conceived without contradiction and that these realities are mutually exclusive. For example, “God operating in the world” and “the Christian God operating in the world” are not mutually exclusive. The former is implied by the latter. For example, one kind of reality may involve the Christian God who operates in the world. Or the Islamic God. Or some invisible spaghetti monster running the world. Etc

Let’s say that one argues that assignments of probabilities to different possible realities being true cannot reasonably be assigned. The rationale for this may be that probabilities seem meaningless or that even if they were meaningful, there is no justification to use the principle of indifference for them. The principle of indifference, as a reminder, states that probabilities among propositions with an absence of knowledge should be equiprobable.

If so, does this imply that one cannot think it to be less reasonable to believe that say the Undetectable Flying Spaghetti Monster is real than the Christian God? Presumably, if one did think this, one would be able to justify an epistemic probability that is higher for the Monster than the Christian God. But as mentioned before, one may refuse to do this.

As such, would one be inconsistent if one fails to assign probabilities but also deems it to think that a certain kind of reality is more reasonable to believe than another?

Comment: The answer to your questions, as always, is Bayesian probability. The principle of indifference only applies in certain special cases, not generally. The more general principle is Occam's razor: a universal prior assigns more probability to universes with shorter minimum-description-lengths. This is Solomonoff's theory of inductive inference.

Comment: Any probability assignment begs the question of why it should be as such. In my example, what would the probability of the Christian God with respect to the Flying Spaghetti Monster be?

Comment: Perhaps, it is unreasonable to put probabilities on different *metaphysical* realities. But that is not what different *possible* "realities" are typically about. We are mostly interested in *one* reality, the one we are in, we just do not know everything about it. And it is often perfectly reasonable to put probabilities on what is or is not in it, including flying spaghetti monsters and gods. It accounts for the scope of our ignorance given what we are reasonably certain about, like background facts and physical laws, not metaphysics.

Comment: @Conifold I don’t see how that evades the meaninglessness of probability being applied here. How does one, for example, attach a figure to the probability of a Flying Spaghetti Monster existing? How does one show that that figure is smaller than that of the Christian God? And lastly, what does it mean for a certain kind of being to “more likely” exist than another, even if all of this is with respect to our reality? The conundrum seems to remain.

Comment: In theory the ideal prior probability of a universe is a function of the minimum description length of the universe: the shortest program that exactly generates all the observations from that universe. In practice we don't know this probability exactly, but we can often get good approximations. The FSM and the Christian God are similar explanations, and so we'd expect them to have similar prior probabilities, and we can't say too much about which is higher. An explanation based on simple laws of physics would be a simpler explanation, and thus it would have a much higher prior probability.

Comment: So this rests on the assumption that a simpler theory has a higher prior probability. This again begs the question of why it should be as such even though it seems intuitive. One may even argue, as theologians do, that god is more simple. Lastly, what does it mean for a theory to have X probability of being true?

Comment: If we had to compare FSM to Christian God, we could note that the Christian God has a complicated mythos attached to it - all of the acts of God in the Bible. In comparison, the FSM is relatively simple, with fewer personality traits, commandments, and actions. So by that, the FSM would be more likely than the Christian God, though both are far less likely and more complicated than an explanation in terms of simple laws of physics.

Comment: One attaches a figure by updating some nominal prior (it doesn't much matter what it is as long as it is non-zero and uniformly assigned) on background knowledge, physical laws and justified personal evidentiary judgments, for example. Spaghetti monsters will not fare well, God will do better, but much will depend on the last ingredient. There is no conundrum there. It is all very down to earth as long as one does not search for nonsensical "metaphysically objective" basis of epistemic probabilities.

Comment: Yeah I suppose the last part of your comment is what I was trying to find. If there is no objective basis for epistemic probabilities, I’m having a hard time justifying why a probability that presumably reduces to just a subjective degree of belief says anything about the world. Sure it may say something about us and what we would do or how we would act given certain scenarios. But how does this help us actually understand what is true about the world as a matter of fact?

Comment: Probabilities are not properties of the events described, they are properties of *your perspective about* the events described. Your perspective is the result of repeatedly applying various heuristics and other mental rules to your observations. You should try to select mental rules that result in perspectives that result in taking *effective actions* in the world. It just so happens that probability is very useful for taking effective actions, considering that we don't know everything about the world; probability represents your own lack of knowledge about the world.

Comment: "Metaphysically epistemic" is just an oxymoron, "epistemic", by definition, depends on subject's state of knowledge and cognitive values in evidentiary judgments. It does not mean that it must be subjective, it means that it must depend on facts about the subject in addition to facts about the world, and on facts about the relations between the world and the subject. It helps because one cannot parse facts about the world from received input without taking into account receiver's state and in what relation it stands to the world. Probabilities estimate how much the input may reflect the world.

Comment: the introduction of metaphysical realities seems pointless, it doesn't add anything to the question of the plausibility of God in this reality.  It seems like just another way of paraphrasing the same question again that has already been answered on this SE more than once.

Answer (score 2):

> As such, would one be inconsistent if one fails to assign probabilities but also deems it to think that a certain kind of reality is more reasonable to believe than another?

I think you have that backwards. Probability, also epistemic probability, is a mathematical model that will not perfectly fit reality (not even "epistemic reality"), but can be helpful in certain (many) situations. If in a certain situation you don't find assigning epistemic probabilities helpful (and you have a good case that what you're talking about is such a situation), then don't do it. Case closed. There is no rule that says probabilities should always be assigned, and if you can't it means XXX. It just means that here it doesn't seem convincing and helpful, nothing more than that. (Of course somebody else might do it, and then you are free to find their arguments convincing or not.)

Comment: The "*Here be dragons*" part of the map. Mount Olympus, for example.

Answer (score 1):

One may not reasonably be able to assign probabilities to different metaphysical realities. But one could potentially assign probabilities to the output of a method of evaluating whether something is true, e.g. apply a method to some claims and see how many you get right.

If your method is "believe everything you see", you may misclassify dreams, illusions or other mental conjurations.

If you refine this to exclude dreams and verify what you see, your misclassifications would go down, and the method would have a higher accuracy percentage (even if you can't assign a probability to a particular dream being true).

There are also multiple probabilities to consider, which can be based on some combination of [true positives, true negatives, false positives, and false negatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives).

The problem of figuring out whether even one belief (beyond ["I am"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum)) is true may not be trivial, considering the unprovability of [the existence of external reality and other minds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism). This may e.g. lead to some form or variant of [coherentism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherentism), and considering whether a particular model, when applied consistently, produces internally consistent results.

If you *cannot* independently verify whether a claim is true, in some way, then that claim cannot serve as support for a method. If a method produced no independently verified claims, then, under this view, it cannot be deemed "good", and it certainly cannot be deemed "better" than any method that has produced independently verified claims (even if unreliably, although if it also hasn't produced disproven claims, it's not necessarily "worse" either - we just wouldn't have enough information to trust it).

Comment: "Excluding dreams" is ontically kosher; epistemically not: because the fact of the matter is we all enter dreams *inadvertently* but wake up *knowingly*. This asymmetry of recognizing the dream state makes knowing "This is not a dream" epistemically and hence ontically infeasible

Comment: @Rushi The important time to recognise that a dream is a dream is after you've woken up. Recognising this while dreaming is less important, because actions taken in a dream don't generally affect things outside of that dream (and most people also don't have much conscious control over actions taken in dreams in any case... or maybe that's just me; there is lucid dreaming, which involves taking conscious control, but this also involves *knowing* that you're dreaming). As for whether *this* is a dream, that relates back to what I said about coherentism.

Comment: As someone who's experienced nested dreams [I once woke out from dream to waking 4 times] which landed me into this socalled waking state, to me it's a highly non academic question: *Is there a fifth awakening waiting to happen?*

Comment: Awww... You removed ur [totem-top](https://inception.fandom.com/wiki/Totem) comment. I liked it though I'd be hard pressed to say why!

Comment: Boy, finding out the truth is hard work! Wouldn't you think we would know it by now? If billions of people haven't, maybe we should just move on to something more pressing?